# Getting this error in MS Teams graph API: "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value"

Tags: microsoft-teams

When I create a group in MS Teams using REST API in postman.

URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups

Request Body:

```
{
  "description": "Self help community for golf",
  "displayName": "Golf Assist",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "golfassist",
  "securityEnabled": false
}
```

I got an error. Error is given below.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "4a57c3e2-47a4-46bd-a5bb-a00a612fd613",
            "date": "2019-04-02T16:31:30"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: This API is not in beta anymore. Does it work with v1.0 instead of beta?

Comment: No it doesn't work with v1.0. When i add v1.0 replace with beta. I got new error.  "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
"message": "Method not allowed."

Answer (score 1):

We've checked the logs on your request and it appears that you are calling the graph with a Microsoft Account (aka MSA) versus an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) account. Microsoft Graph APIs for Teams do not support MSA accounts, only Azure AD accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the Same exact error when trying to Create a Shift in Teams.
This one is still in Beta.